# Darkest matter on Earth ("pure black")

Tags: visible-light, matter

What is (for a human's eyes) the natural or synthetical matter on Earth (i.e. not in Space) that emits the least quantity of visible photons while being lightened by sunlight?

In this matter, how is light converted? Invisible wavelengths (ultraviolet, X-rays)? Heat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"[Vantablack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack), made out of carbon nanotubes, is designed by Surrey NanoSystems and absorbs 99.96% of all light that hits it. Conventional black, such as black paint or fabric, absorbs between 95% and 98% of light."

Comment: OMG it's blacker than space!

Comment: So it's a trap make of nanotubes which catch up the light until it is converted into heat... interesting, thanks.